# How to apply a jQuery click event to multiple ID's

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the code below you can see I am running this block of code over and over just changing the `ID` selector...

Is there a better way to crunch this down into 1 small block and simply change the `#line-1-font` so the number can be any number?

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", "#line-1-font", function( event ) {
    $('<link>')
      .appendTo($('head'))
      .attr({type : 'text/css', rel : 'stylesheet'})
      .attr('href', 'fonts/'+$(this).val()+'-font.css');
    $(this).prev().css("font-family", $(this).val());
});
```

//

```
// Change FONTS
$( "body" ).on( "click", "#line-1-font", function( event ) {
    $('<link>')
      .appendTo($('head'))
      .attr({type : 'text/css', rel : 'stylesheet'})
      .attr('href', 'fonts/'+$(this).val()+'-font.css');
    $(this).prev().css("font-family", $(this).val());
});

$( "body" ).on( "click", "#line-2-font", function( event ) {
    $('<link>')
      .appendTo($('head'))
      .attr({type : 'text/css', rel : 'stylesheet'})
      .attr('href', 'fonts/'+$(this).val()+'-font.css');
    $(this).prev().css("font-family", $(this).val());
});

$( "body" ).on( "click", "#line-3-font", function( event ) {
    $('<link>')
      .appendTo($('head'))
      .attr({type : 'text/css', rel : 'stylesheet'})
      .attr('href', 'fonts/'+$(this).val()+'-font.css');
    $(this).prev().css("font-family", $(this).val());
});

$( "body" ).on( "click", "#line-4-font", function( event ) {
    $('<link>')
      .appendTo($('head'))
      .attr({type : 'text/css', rel : 'stylesheet'})
      .attr('href', 'fonts/'+$(this).val()+'-font.css');
    $(this).prev().css("font-family", $(this).val());
});

$( "body" ).on( "click", "#line-5-font", function( event ) {
    $('<link>')
      .appendTo($('head'))
      .attr({type : 'text/css', rel : 'stylesheet'})
      .attr('href', 'fonts/'+$(this).val()+'-font.css');
    $(this).prev().css("font-family", $(this).val());
});

$( "body" ).on( "click", "#line-6-font", function( event ) {
    $('<link>')
      .appendTo($('head'))
      .attr({type : 'text/css', rel : 'stylesheet'})
      .attr('href', 'fonts/'+$(this).val()+'-font.css');
    $(this).prev().css("font-family", $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: How's the html maybe you can use a different selector that selects all of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can do that:

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", "[id^='line-'][id$='-font']", function( event ) {
    $('<link>')
      .appendTo($('head'))
      .attr({type : 'text/css', rel : 'stylesheet'})
      .attr('href', 'fonts/'+$(this).val()+'-font.css');
    $(this).prev().css("font-family", $(this).val());
});
```

But you can add a common class to them and refer it like

```
$('body').on('click','.yourClass',function(){
    ... // your code goes here
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Assign a class to all the relevant id's and bind the event to the class.